# Update table in MS Access from views exported from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have created a table and need to update the entries by comparing the data from the view that I have created in SQL server

This action need to performed by a button click in MS Access forms

I have written the following query in MS Access - Query. Exported the view totaltemp1 from sql server.

> update P_Payroll as p
>
> inner join totaltemp1 as tp on p.emp_id = tp.emp_id
>
> inner join P_Student_Supervisor as ss on tp.emp_id = ss.emp_id
>
> set Number_of_Hours = tp.temp_drop_hours,
>
> Total_Payment = tp.temp_drop_hours*ss.emp_hourlywage
>
> where p.emp_id = tp.emp_id and ss.emp_id = p.emp_id;

Previously I got this working correctly in SQL server in stand alone mode. Code for that as follows.

> update P_Payroll set Number_of_Hours = tp.temp_drop_hours, Total_Payment = tp.temp_drop_hours*ss.emp_hourlywage
> from totaltemp1 as tp, P_Payroll as p, P_Student_Supervisor as ss
> where p.emp_id = tp.emp_id and ss.emp_id = p.emp_id;

I have checked the data structure too. I am just getting an error

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'p.emp_id = tp.emp_id inner join P_Student_Supervisor as ss on tp.emp_id = ss.emp_i"

Thanks for your time

Pk.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the table `p` - change to `update P_Payroll as p`.

Comment: I missed copying it here. I got the same exact error anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can check...  first, remove the WHERE clause - you're already specifying those conditions in the JOIN statements.

Then, put brackets around your joins...

```
UPDATE (P_Payroll AS p
INNER JOIN totaltemp1 AS tp on p.emp_id = tp.emp_id)
INNER JOIN P_Student_Supervisor AS ss on tp.emp_id = ss.emp_id
SET p.Number_of_Hours = tp.temp_drop_hours, 
    p.Total_Payment = tp.temp_drop_hours * ss.emp_hourlywage
```

Access like brackets...